# fonts in mathmode

Tags: math-mode, fonts

I would like to ask if there exists anywhere a font for math mode that is as similar as possible to the font called "Avenir" (or else Helvetica Neue, Helvetica or Verdana) ?

Cheers

Edit: as to the context, I would like to set up a table which is composed partly of text and partly of mathematical expressions, and since my normal text font (avenir in my case) is very different from the default math mode font, the whole table has a displeasing look at the end

Comment: So you are looking for a sans-serif math font?

Comment: Does Avenir support maths? If so, you can use it with Xe/LuaTeX.  [The LaTeX Font Catalogue](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/mathfonts.html) has a page on fonts for maths using traditional engines such as TeX and pdfTeX.

Comment: Arev, Iwona, GFS Neohellenic, KP Sans-Serif, Kurier...?

Comment: @MaxNoe yes I am, if possible Avenir

Comment: @cfr I don't know LaTeX so very well honestly... therefore I would guess that avenir does not support math mode. But then again the only way to change the appearance of math mode which I know is with \usepackage{euler}. What would be the command to use to set another font as math mode ?

Comment: Did you look at the link I posted? If you click on a font you like, it will show you more details, including the commands needed for (pdf)TeX.

Comment: @cfr that would be great :) I like erewhon and heuristica

Comment: So not sans-serif after all? ;) In any case, the principle is the same: click the font you like and find the commands you need....

Comment: I've edited my answer to illustrate those, but you can easily take the relevant code lines from the catalogue if you have third thoughts ;).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just follow the instructions provided by [The LaTeX Font Catalogue](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/mathfonts.html) if one of the fonts they illustrate is suitable. Just click on the font you like and copy the code lines into your preamble.

For example if you want to use [Kurier](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/kurier/):

[image: Kurier]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[math]{kurier}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
\[
\Pr(P) = \frac{\mu_0}{4\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{x^{-3c^3}}{\sqrt{c^7-\phi_9}}
\]
\end{document}
```

Or for [KP Sans-Serif](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/kpsans/):

[image: KP Sans-Serif]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[sfmath]{kpfonts}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
\[
\Pr(P) = \frac{\mu_0}{4\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{x^{-3c^3}}{\sqrt{c^7-\phi_9}}
\]
\end{document}
```

Or [Arev](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/arev/):

[image: Arev]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{arev}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
\[
\Pr(P) = \frac{\mu_0}{4\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{x^{-3c^3}}{\sqrt{c^7-\phi_9}}
\]
\end{document}
```

## EDIT

Based on comments, you seem to have abandoned the preference for sans-serif and mentioned Erewhon and Heuristica. So...

[Heuristica](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/heuristica/):

[image: Heuristica]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{heuristica}
\usepackage[heuristica,vvarbb,bigdelims]{newtxmath}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\renewcommand*\oldstylenums[1]{\textosf{#1}}
\begin{document}
\[
\Pr(P) = \frac{\mu_0}{4\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{x^{-3c^3}}{\sqrt{c^7-\phi_9}}
\]
\end{document}
```

[Erewhon](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/erewhon/):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[proportional,scaled=1.064]{erewhon}
\usepackage[erewhon,vvarbb,bigdelims]{newtxmath}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\renewcommand*\oldstylenums[1]{\textosf{#1}}
\begin{document}
\[
\Pr(P) = \frac{\mu_0}{4\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{x^{-3c^3}}{\sqrt{c^7-\phi_9}}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image: Erewhon]