Setting default main font for scr-classes
I'm just new to kOMA-SCRIPT classes, I want to typeset my 'scrartcl' document's main body text to helvetica's (helvet) phv font style. I tried the following commands but failed. I was able to change the font style of the Sections and subsection titles font style, but I was unable to do the same for the text of the body for entire document. please, anyone who knows this, help.
\documentclass[a4paper, headsepline=true, twocolumn]{scrartcl}
%\automark[subsction]{section}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=0.6in,right=0.5in,top=0.7in,bottom=0.7in]{geometry}

\renewcommand{\normalsize}{\fontsize{11pt}{18pt}\selectfont} 

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[babel]{microtype}
\usepackage[babel, english, german=guillemets]{csquotes}

\usepackage[table, dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\colorlet{lv}{Violet!20}
\colorlet{r1}{DarkOrchid!20}
\colorlet{r2}{Green!30}
\colorlet{r3}{Orange!30}
\colorlet{R2}{Tan!30}
\usepackage{soul,color}
\newcommand{\hlc}[2][yellow]{ {\sethlcolor{#1} \hl{#2}} }

 

\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem} 
\usepackage{times,mathptmx}
\usepackage{lmodern, helvet}
\fontfamily{phv}\selectfont
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{ptm}
%\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\setkomafont{disposition}{\normalfont\scshape\bfseries\rmfamily}
\setkomafont{section}{\bfseries \sffamily\LARGE}   \setkomafont{subsection}{\bfseries \sffamily \large}      \setkomafont{subsubsection}{ \bfseries \sffamily}


\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{amsmath,graphicx} %eps figures can be used instead
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage[format=plain,justification=raggedright,singlelinecheck=false,font=small,labelfont=bf,labelsep=space]{caption}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xr}
\usepackage[unicode, bookmarks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newcommand{\red}[1]{\textcolor{red}{#1}}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2212}{-}
\hypersetup{pdfauthor={Akshay Hegde}}
\hypersetup{ colorlinks, linkcolor={red!50!black}, citecolor={blue!50!green}, urlcolor={blue!80!green}}



\usepackage{svg}
\usepackage{makecell}

\usepackage{incgraph,graphicx,subcaption}




\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{0.5mm}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{8pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2.5}

\newcommand{\inch}{\ensuremath{\,\textrm{in.}}}


%\usepackage{fontspec}  \defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text,Scale=MatchLowercase}     \setmainfont{Times}   \setmonofont{Lucida Sans Typewriter}


\usepackage{newtxtext} 
\usepackage{newtxmath}


%% Fonts
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{siunitx}  \DeclareSIPower\sq\square{2}    \DeclareSIUnit[quantity-product = {}]\mApsqcm{\text{mA\,cm$^{-2}$}}     \DeclareSIUnit[quantity-product = {}]\mVpd{\text{mV\,dec$^{-1}$}}
\newcommand\tsub[1]{\textsubscript{#1}}
\newcommand\tsup[1]{\textsuperscript{#1}}
\newcommand\tmin[1]{\textminus}

%% Bibliography
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=ieee, dashed=false,url=false,isbn=false,defernumbers=true, citestyle=numeric-comp, natbib]{biblatex}    \bibliography{ref1}  %[refsection=section, texencoding=ascii] into biblatex load
%\addbibresource{ref1.bib}
%\usepackage[square,numbers, sort&compress,comma]{natbib}   
\newcommand*{\doi}[1]{\href{http://dx.doi.org/#1}{doi: #1}}
%\usepackage{jabbrv}  \DeclareFieldInputHandler{journaltitle}{    \def\NewValue{\JournalTitle{#1}}}


\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{0.5mm}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{18pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2.5}
%\newcommand{\inch}{\ensuremath{\,\textrm{in.}}}



\title{TITLE}
\author{AKSHAY PRAKASH HEGDE}
\date{May 2024}

\begin{document}
\section{something which I could change}
some body-text which I couldn't
\end{document}   ```


Welcome to TeX.SE

Hope this https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/261556/fonts-in-mathmode will helps you

Please don't redefine \normalsize. This will cause all kinds of trouble and break almost everything. You are doing all kinds of conflicting things with fonts by loading conflicting packages and overwriting them with others. Go through the preamble and figure out what you actually want to use. \renewcommand\familydefault{\sffamily} will set the default font to sans. (Maybe KOMA has something more specific.)

You should really, really try to minimize your example. Usually you would than find out, that you don't needed several of the packages to reproduce the issue. I wouldn't be surprised, if you would even find the root of your problem … If not, see my answer.

There are several issues with your code. The issue, that is relevant for the problem is: Fiddling with packages and code without knowing, what they are doing. More specific: Using several font packages and font usage definitions in random order:
\usepackage{times,mathptmx}

Here you first load package times and mathptmx. Both change the roman default (\rmdefault) to a Times font and do this almost the same. times also changes the sans-serif default (\sfdefault) to a Helvetica font and the typewriter default (\ttdefault) to a Courier font. mathptmx instead also changes the math font to a mixture of Times and other fonts. So the combination of these package could be done, but shouldn't. Both packages are obsolete. times is explicitly declared as obsolete in psnfss2e.pdf, the manual of psnfss which, e.g., describes mathptmx.
\usepackage{lmodern, helvet}

Now you are loading font package lmodern, which again changes the defaults of roman font, sans-serif font and typewriter font and also of the math fonts to Latin Modern. And you are loading font package helvet, which changes the sans-serif font so a Helvetica font. All previous font settings are overwritten now.
\fontfamily{phv}\selectfont

This only changes the currently used font to Helvetica. It does not change the font used by font commands like \normalfont (often used implicitly to reset the font to the default document font), \sffamily, \textsf etc. So using this in the preamble is seldom useful.
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{ptm}

This would again change the roman default. So previous changes to this, e.g., by loading lmodern are now overwritten.
%\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

If you wouldn't have commented this line, it would indeed change the default font (used, e.g., by \normalfont) to the sans-serif family. For your purpose this command is recommended.
\usepackage{newtxtext} 
\usepackage{newtxmath}

These packages again changes the roman default and the math font to a Times font. It is indeed recommend, if you want to use Times. But it also changes the \familydefault to \rmdefault and therefore the normal font to use the roman font. So it would overwrite a previous change of \familydefault. By default newtxtext also changes the sans-serif default to Helvetica and the typewriter to ntxtt. Using these two package to switch to Times + Helvetica is indeed one of the recommended solutions.
Note: All the issues above are independent from using a KOMA-Script class or not.
So to answer your question:

Remove all font packages but those, you want to use.
Redefine \familydefault to \sfdefault after loading all font packages.

To show this as a real minimal document (and it really doesn't matter, whether you are using a KOMA-Script class or a standard class):
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{newtx}% Load newtxtext + newtxmath to use a combination of Times (roman default) + Helvetica (sans-serif default).
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}% Use the default sans-serif font as default/normal font.

\usepackage{blindtext}% for demonstration only

\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\end{document}


And to correct only the font issue of your document:
\documentclass[a4paper, headsepline=true, twocolumn]{scrartcl}
%\automark[subsction]{section}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=0.6in,right=0.5in,top=0.7in,bottom=0.7in]{geometry}

\renewcommand{\normalsize}{\fontsize{11pt}{18pt}\selectfont}% Note: Maybe it
                                % would be better to use package setspace and
                                % command \setstretch or \linespread to not
                                % only affect the normal size.

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}% Not needed for more than 10 years.
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[babel]{microtype}
\usepackage[babel, english, german=guillemets]{csquotes}

\usepackage[table, dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\colorlet{lv}{Violet!20}
\colorlet{r1}{DarkOrchid!20}
\colorlet{r2}{Green!30}
\colorlet{r3}{Orange!30}
\colorlet{R2}{Tan!30}
\usepackage{soul,color}
\newcommand{\hlc}[2][yellow]{ {\sethlcolor{#1} \hl{#2}} }% There are orphan
                                % spaces in this code, so you should fix it!

 

\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem} 
\setkomafont{disposition}{\normalfont\scshape\bfseries\rmfamily}% \normalfont
                                % not needed and you are explicitly using the
                                % roman font here (Times not Helvetica!)
\setkomafont{section}{\bfseries \sffamily\LARGE}% \bfseries\sffamily not needed here
\setkomafont{subsection}{\bfseries \sffamily \large}% \bfseries\sffamily not needed here
\setkomafont{subsubsection}{ \bfseries \sffamily}% \bfseries\sffamily not needed here


\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{amsmath,graphicx} %eps figures can be used instead
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage[format=plain,justification=raggedright,singlelinecheck=false,font=small,labelfont=bf,labelsep=space]{caption}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage{graphicx}% already loaded before
\usepackage{xr}
\usepackage[unicode, bookmarks]{hyperref}% too early
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newcommand{\red}[1]{\textcolor{red}{#1}}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2212}{-}
\hypersetup{pdfauthor={Akshay Hegde}}
\hypersetup{ colorlinks, linkcolor={red!50!black}, citecolor={blue!50!green}, urlcolor={blue!80!green}}



\usepackage{svg}
\usepackage{makecell}

\usepackage{incgraph,graphicx,subcaption}% graphicx already loaded twice before




\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{0.5mm}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{8pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2.5}

\newcommand{\inch}{\ensuremath{\,\textrm{in.}}}% I would recommend to use
                                % package siunitx instead.


\usepackage{newtxtext}% you can replace these
\usepackage{newtxmath}% two by \usepackage{newtx}


%% Fonts
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{siunitx}  \DeclareSIPower\sq\square{2}    \DeclareSIUnit[quantity-product = {}]\mApsqcm{\text{mA\,cm$^{-2}$}}     \DeclareSIUnit[quantity-product = {}]\mVpd{\text{mV\,dec$^{-1}$}}
\newcommand\tsub[1]{\textsubscript{#1}}
\newcommand\tsup[1]{\textsuperscript{#1}}
\newcommand\tmin[1]{\textminus}

%% Bibliography
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=ieee, dashed=false,url=false,isbn=false,defernumbers=true, citestyle=numeric-comp, natbib]{biblatex}    \bibliography{ref1}  %[refsection=section, texencoding=ascii] into biblatex load
%\addbibresource{ref1.bib}
%\usepackage[square,numbers, sort&compress,comma]{natbib}   
\newcommand*{\doi}[1]{\href{http://dx.doi.org/#1}{doi: #1}}
%\usepackage{jabbrv}  \DeclareFieldInputHandler{journaltitle}{    \def\NewValue{\JournalTitle{#1}}}


\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{0.5mm}% You've changed \arrayrulewidth, \tabcolsep
                                % and \arraystrech already
                                % before. So you should clean up the preamble
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{18pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2.5}
%\newcommand{\inch}{\ensuremath{\,\textrm{in.}}}

\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault}% Use the sans-serif font as default
                                % document font.

\title{TITLE}
\author{AKSHAY PRAKASH HEGDE}
\date{May 2024}

\begin{document}
\section{something which I could change}
some body-text which I couldn't
\end{document}   ```


And if you want everything (text, math, etc.) in sans-serif, have a look at, e.g.,

What is the simplest way to typeset an entire document in sans-serif?
Typeset mathematical symbols also in sans serif font?
Which OpenType Math fonts are available?
fonts in mathmode


To begin with, don't load packages if you don't know what they do. In other words, don't take your friend's preamble and add to it.
The lines
\usepackage{times,mathptmx}
\usepackage{lmodern, helvet}
\fontfamily{phv}\selectfont
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{ptm}

are a clear example of something that's being augmented step-by-step by different people who took their friend's preamble and added to it, without knowing about the purpose of loaded packages.
Loading multiple font packages just makes LaTeX spinning its wheels for nothing and, in some cases, it can lead to puzzling output.
Other examples: the code
\DeclareSIPower\sq\square{2}
\DeclareSIUnit[quantity-product = {}]\mApsqcm{\text{mA\,cm$^{-2}$}}     
\DeclareSIUnit[quantity-product = {}]\mVpd{\text{mV\,dec$^{-1}$}}

is, to say the least, very dubious. You're defining abbreviations for derived units, so it should be
\DeclareSIPower\sq\square{2}
\DeclareSIUnit{\decade}{dec}
\newcommand{\mApsqcm}{\milli\ampere\per\centi\meter\squared}
\newcommand{\mVpd}{\milli\volt\per\decade}

and, of course, product-quantity={} should not be used.
What you want for your specific problem is to load helvet and to make sans-serif the default, so just
\usepackage[scaled=0.9]{helvet}

\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

the latter line near the end of the preamble, where last minute settings are done.
In the code below I left most of the packages you loaded, but in the correct order; for instance, hyperref should be (almost) last and instead of the bookmarks option it's better to load the bookmark package.
Load packages first, then apply settings and do definitions. But, for your own sanity, remove the packages you don't actually use.
\documentclass[a4paper, headsepline=true, twocolumn,11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=0.6in,right=0.5in,top=0.7in,bottom=0.7in]{geometry}

%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}% <--- not needed
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage[babel]{microtype}
\usepackage[babel, english, german=guillemets]{csquotes}

\usepackage[scaled=0.9]{helvet}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[table, dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem} 
\usepackage{float}% <--- why?
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage[
  format=plain,
  justification=raggedright,
  singlelinecheck=false,
  font=small,
  labelfont=bf,
  labelsep=space
]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{xr}
\usepackage{svg}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{incgraph}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[mode=text]{siunitx}

%% Bibliography
\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  style=ieee,
  dashed=false,
  url=false,
  isbn=false,
  defernumbers=true,
  citestyle=numeric-comp,
  natbib
]{biblatex}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}


\colorlet{lv}{Violet!20}
\colorlet{r1}{DarkOrchid!20}
\colorlet{r2}{Green!30}
\colorlet{r3}{Orange!30}
\colorlet{R2}{Tan!30}
\newcommand{\hlc}[2][yellow]{{\sethlcolor{#1}\hl{#2}}}% <--- no spaces

%%%%%%%%%%%%

\newcommand{\red}[1]{\textcolor{red}{#1}}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2212}{-}

\hypersetup{
  pdfauthor={Akshay Hegde},
  colorlinks,
  linkcolor={red!50!black},
  citecolor={blue!50!green},
  urlcolor={blue!80!green},
}

%% siunitx
\DeclareSIPower\sq\square{2}
\DeclareSIUnit{\decade}{dec}
\DeclareSIUnit}{\inch}{in}
\newcommand{\mApsqcm}{\milli\ampere\per\centi\meter\squared}
\newcommand{\mVpd}{\milli\volt\per\decade}

\newcommand\tsub[1]{\textsubscript{#1}}
\newcommand\tsup[1]{\textsuperscript{#1}}
\newcommand\tmin[1]{\textminus}

\addbibresource{ref1.bib}
\newcommand*{\doi}[1]{\href{http://dx.doi.org/#1}{doi: #1}}


%\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{0.5mm}% <--- Why?
%\setlength{\tabcolsep}{18pt}% <--- Why?
%\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2.5}% <--- Why?

\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\title{TITLE}
\author{AKSHAY PRAKASH HEGDE}
\date{May 2024}

\begin{document}
\section{something which I could change}
some body-text which I couldn't

\qty{1.2}{\mApsqcm}

\qty{2.4}{\mVpd}


\end{document} 



Thanks for the description. Is that float package to set the float where they should be using [H} in front..? like \begin{figure}[H], what else can be done for this...?

@AKSHAYPRAKASHHEGDE Don’t use [H]. It makes for bad page breaks.

In this, how do I set the font size to, for example, 10.5pt...? it was giving the warning  Font shape `T1/qhv/m/sl' in size <10.95> not available when I used the 10.5pt option.

@AKSHAYPRAKASHHEGDE There is no 10.5pt option, but scrartcl has many ways to set the font size.

I found one simple solution; I experimented and just added the following command line (i.e., inserted \fontfamily{"font code"} in the line defining the document font size. ;  4th line of the questions code.) i.e.,
 \renewcommand{\normalsize}{\upshape\fontfamily{phv}\fontsize{11pt}{18pt}\selectfont}  
it worked fine, but the problem is you can't get any size you want except for the defined size for the particular font.!
any solid solutions, if any have, please post them.

Please edit or delete this. This is a Seriously Bad Idea. Redefining \normalsize is just nuts. You cannot possibly expect anything to do anything sensible if you insert arbitrary sabotage like this.

This hack does not really solve the cause of the problem, but merely removes a symptom of the actual cause. But at the cost of new problems and not really reliably. Simply insert a \normalfont into the document once and the Roman font is back. So: Nobody should ever use this!
